# Apache version 7 MPM config depends on application sizing

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration-files

Our client use these settings and wanted me to suggest new setting by Application size.

Current Recommended, Generic:

```
ThreadLimit 200
ServerLimit 4
StartServers 2
MaxClients 800
MinSpareThreads 200
MaxSpareThreads 400
ThreadsPerChild 200
MaxRequestsPerChild 30000
```

Need info suggestions and reason for

Application Sizing (definitions)

```
SMALL - 0 - 10k hits/day
MEDIUM 10k - 100k hits/day
LARGE - <100k hits/day
```

Comment: Isn't it way more suitable for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)?

Comment: I dont knw, I'm new to these changes

Comment: It just my opinion, but this question appears to deal mostly with optimal Server configuration. Not programming directly. As StackOverlow supposed to be used.

Comment: yeah these are apache configurations